# Check which column matched on MySQL like query

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it possible to find out which column was matched against on a multiple LIKE query?

e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col_a LIKE = '%B' OR col_b LIKE = '%A'

if(MATCHED COL_A){
   do this;
}else{
   do that;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply put your conditions in select statement and name it with new alias which will have a boolean value 0/1 for matching columns,Also `=` after like doesn't make any sense

```
SELECT *,
col_a LIKE  '%B' AS match_cola,
col_b LIKE  '%A' AS match_colb
FROM table WHERE col_a LIKE '%B' OR col_b LIKE '%A'
```

Fetching result from query you can check it as

```
$result = fetch result from query;
//loop
if($result['match_cola'] == 1){
echo 'col_a matched';
}
//end loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table WHERE col_a LIKE "%B" OR col_b LIKE "%A"

if (strpos($colA, $needle) !== false) {
// do this
} elseif (strpos($colB, $needle) !== false) {
// do that
}
```